# Issue of RenderSection in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is code in _layout.cshtml:

```
@{
        Boolean Yes=true;
        if (Yes == true)
        {
            RenderSection("one", false);
        }
        else
        {
            RenderSection("two", false);
        }
    }
```

And here is code in index.cshtml:

```
@section one{
    1111111111111111111111111111111
}
@section two{
    2222222222222222222222222222222
}
```

When I runned the IIS,it report this error:
[image]
I don't konw why it occur this error.I tried something and found if I move the RenderSection single,like:
@RenderSection("one", false)
Then it works.
What's wrong with my code?I knowed it is just a stupid question,and I tried my best but can not solve it.
Please help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The section `two` not have in Layout due to "Yes" variable have value is `true`.

But in the index.cshtml, you call `@section two`.

So when the view render, the `_Layout.cshtml` will try to add `22222...` to the body in section `two` but not found the section `two`.

That why you see the exception that you not have defined section `two`.

---

To correct your code, you still give 2 section in `_Layout.cshtml`

```
@RenderSection("one", false)
@RenderSection("two", false)
```

then in your `index.cshtml`

```
@{
    Boolean Yes = true;
    if (Yes == true)
    {
        @section one{
            1111111111111111111111111111111
        }
    }
    else
    {
        @section two{
           2222222222222222222222222222222
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However,I wanna to custom the section every page.If I set it in layout page,then I can't custom it now.

Comment: Totally I wanna to use a variable to decide which to render in every page,so I used section to do it.